# Django Email Backend

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I'm developing a django app locally and trying to configure it to use the Amazone SES service to send emails. I've installed [django-ses](https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses) and added this to my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '...'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '...'
```

Unfortunately, mail.get_connection() returns that it's still using django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend; both in the shell and when the development server is running.

It behaved the same when I was attempting to go the normal smtp configuration route with django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend too...

Any ideas as to why it's not making the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_BACKEND) the default value for EMAIL_BACKEND is `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`, not `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`, so it has probably been set again later in the settings file.

You can also print the value of EMAIL_BACKEND to make sure if the problem is in the function or the variable.

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
```

Comment: Yes. You were right about it being set elsewhere. I'm using wagtail as well and the dev.py settings file was setting the email backend to console. Thanks!